# entity framework - inner join to left join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, join

Good day! I need transform join to left join in my query -

```
        var query = (from sections in context.Sections
                     join themes in context.Themes on sections.SectionId equals themes.SectionId
                     join comments in context.Comments on themes.ThemeId equals comments.ThemeId
                     select new { sections.SectionId, sections.SectionTitle, themes.ThemeId, comments.CommentId } into x
                     group x by new { x.SectionId, x.SectionTitle } into g
                     select new SectionInfo
                     {
                         SectionId = g.Key.SectionId,
                         SectionTitle = g.Key.SectionTitle,
                         ThemeCount = g.Select(s => s.ThemeId).Count(),
                         CommentCount = g.Select(s => s.CommentId).Count()
                     }).ToList();
```

- please, i have no idea(

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DefaultIfEmpty`

One way is like this:

```
from themes in context.Themes.Where(x => sections.SectionId == x.SectionId)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

---

Alternate way

```
join themes in context.Themes on sections.SectionId equals themes.SectionId into themesGroup
from themes in themesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Which part of my query i must replace?

Comment: @user2953816, you need to replace each join you want to convert. In my anwer, you need to replace
`join themes in context.Themes on sections.SectionId equals themes.SectionId`. Do the same thing for your other join